# DOM manipulation in AngularJS 1.5 component

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, dom

I tried to wrap my head around concept of AngularJS component and I kinda started to understand the principle, but when I tried to practice it, I found an example when I'm not sure how to implement it with a component.

I need to implement linear progressbar, it has a template, so logically must be a component, not a directive, but I can't find a way to do DOM manipulations in component and it seems weird to have a directive inside such a little component. Here is the basic implementation with directive:

**JS**

```
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($q, $scope) {

  $scope.curVal= 0;

  $scope.maxVal = 100;

})

.directive('progressBar', [function () {

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        curVal: '@',
        maxVal: '@'
      },
      template: "<div class='progress-bar'>"+
                  "<div class='progress-bar-bar'>testing</div>"+
                "</div>",    

      link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

        function updateProgress() {
          var progress = 0;

          if ($scope.maxVal) {
            progress = Math.min($scope.curVal, $scope.maxVal) / $scope.maxVal * element.find('.progress-bar').width();
          }

          element.find('.progress-bar-bar').css('width', progress);          
        }

        $scope.$watch('curVal', updateProgress);
        $scope.$watch('maxVal', updateProgress);        
      }
    };  
 }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<progress-bar cur-val='{{curVal}}' max-val='{{maxVal}}'>
```

**CSS**

```
.progress-bar {
  width: 120px;
  height: 18px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: rgba(100,50,100,.60);
  border-color: #aaa;  
}

.progress-bar-bar {
  width: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(100,50,100);
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal
}
```

So, maybe I understood the principle of a component wrong, but I really googled a lot about it and thought that I understood the principle before I faced this example.

So my question is: Can I manipulate DOM in component in any way and if the answer is no, what is the way to implement this directive in component (and is it suitable at all)? I don't feel that adding directive to component just to change some CSS is an appropriate choice, so I'm stuck.

Comment: wouldn't need any dom manipulation or any of the js in your link if you used `ng-style`

Comment: @charlietfl oops, it looks like I really can use ng-style and pass value there,  now it looks obvious, thank you, I think you can post it as an answer

Comment: Do you need to make work your directive, or you need a new component approach? The checked answer remains the directive, and doesn't answer the question

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I need component approach, but as I understood, I need to use directive inside component anyway, ng-style or the custom one, am I right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To address your confusion about component vs directive, to use one over the other is a matter of how you design your application.

If you prefer to stick to an MVC (MVVM, MVW, MV*) architecture, it makes little sense to have components. You just create views, controlled by controllers and directives that will modify or control some DOM elements.

In an **MV*** app there are some cases where you **really** want to separate a block from the rest of the page and even make it reusable. You still can make a component for it but it makes more sense in that architecture to stick with a directive.

Since 1.5, directive come very close to what components are. You can get rid of the scope, create a controller...etc, you just have a little more boilerplate code to write.

If you want your app to follow a **component architecture** (react, web components, angular2...etc.) then everything in the application should be a component. (login, navigation, footer...etc) and components can have smaller components. (a file upload component could contain a progress bar component)

When more **control over DOM** elements is needed, this is when you use directives.
If no existing angular directive work for you (ngStyle, ngClass, ngShow...etc.) you create yours. (You want an input to get focus automatically, you can create a directive)

To answer the progress bar thing, this is how I would write its component:

```
var progressBar = {
  bindings: {
    width: '<'
  },
  template: `<div class="meter">
              <span ng-style="{ 'width' : $ctrl.width }"></span>
            </div>`
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/rz8AVALGVl5EiZR1OUdK?p=preview

PS: The css style was copied from [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/) to save time.

Comment: thank you for such a full answer, so as I understand now, angular 1.x is not quite designed for component architecture, it's more about MV* architecture, right? And for component architecture such frameworks as react or angular 2 are more suitable, am I correct? So, for angular 1.x it's better to stick with directives and use components only if there is a need to separate some part of an app, right?

Comment: @IlyaIlin no, from 1.5 and on you can make 100% components based applications. It only depends on you (or your boss) At work every application we start this year are going to be component based (angular2 is not ready for production). Our intranet is made 100% with angular 1.5 components. Some teams are more old school and we stick with MVC in some other projects. (nothing shocking about it either) It's a matter of opinion. Components are more modern (fashion) but the code is really cleaner then what we have with MVC.

Comment: thank you very much, you really made it more clear for me

Answer (score 3):

According to Angular's documentation, any DOM manipulation SHOULD be done using directives. It might be a big work now, but you can always reuse the directive within your project.

"At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element (e.g. via event listeners), or even to transform the DOM element and its children."

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

here's is how you will change the css using the directive

```
app.directive('changeStyle', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {          
       scope.$watch(attrs.myAttr, function (value) {     
         element.css('background-color', (value ? 'transparent' : attrs.myBgcolor));            
       });                      
    }
}
```

});

Comment: thanks, I think I can also use ng-style, as @charlietfl mentioned, 2 ways to solve the problem

Comment: You can also use ng-class if its a simple css change

Comment: sorry, for me the answer by @JoaozitoPolo looks more correct, but I can be wrong, correct me if I am

Answer (score 2):

I made a similar component for example. Look at style replacement definition:

template (myDiv.html):

```
<div class="bgDiv" style="color: {{ $ctrl.color }}">
    myDiv
</div>
```

declares:

```
component('myDiv', {
    templateUrl: 'myDiv.html',
    bindings: {
        color: '='
    }
})
```

see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sV1yYpDKHnhBTu03pFkx?p=preview)

Comment: thanks, it's actually hard to choose the most correct answer, but your one uses less dependencies, so I'll mark it as correct

Comment: oh, sorry, t's really hard to choose only one correct answer

Comment: don't worry. I also prefer the @gyc answer, it's more explained and contains the component